# Cannot drop constraint with postgres even using adminer or sql command CONSTRAINT DOESN'T EXIST

Tags: postgresql

I cannot drop a constraint in postgres even using adminer

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
DROP CONSTRAINT constraint_name;
```

Error in query : ERROR: constraint "constraint_name" of relation "table_name" does not exist

but if I create a new one like :

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD CONSTRAINT my_new_constraint(column1, column2, ... column_n);
```

Then it works and I can drop it.

The one who made the constraint I try to drop did it this way two years ago:

```
create unique index constraint_name on table_name (column1,lower(column2),coalesce(deleted_at,\'19000101\')
```

If anyone has got any idea to drop this constraint?

Comment: What is your intention here: `coalesce(deleted_at,\'19000101\')` ?

Comment: I have just tried to drop the index using this and it worked !!! Thank you
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html) creates an index that needs to be dropped with [`DROP INDEX`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-dropindex.html), not a table constraint.